# Changing legend title and labels in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am new to R, having just recently taken it up.

I have generated a plot, shown with two separate lines of data which is linked here:

[image: 1]

My current code for the graph is:

```
ggplot(Stats, aes(x=Well))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Historic.Mean, colour="red", group="red"))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=Recent.Mean, colour="blue", group="blue"))+ 
  labs(x="Well", y="Water Level (m)", title="Historic vs Recent Well Levels")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name= "Means", labels= c("Historic", "Recent"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

Running this code, generated the plot previously shown, but has not updated the legend title and labels appropriately for some reason.

I have also tried including fill= "legend title" in the labs section instead of the "scale_fill_discrete" which has not worked.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally selected `fill` when you are actually using `colour`. The plot therefore provides labels for a `fill` element, however since such does not exist, nothing appears to happen. Change `scale_fill_discrete` to `scale_colour_discrete`.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, reconsider using tidy principles for handling your data, I can't see the structures of your data, but if you for the future maintain all information in a data.frame, it would be so much easier for you to generate plots, and write re-readable code for your future self. e.g. colours could be asigned by stating `aes( x=Well, colour = group)`. Alternately if you want to decide the colour/hexcode, feed a named vector `clrs <- c("red" = "Historic", "blue" = "Recent")` to `scale_colour_manual(values =  clrs)`

Comment: Also @LilRPro in Since the Question is now closed, but you got your answer, could you help future R newcomers by perhaps rewriting your question with a repoducible example - One way would be to use the iris dataset with e.g. x = Species, y = Sepal.length etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to see where you've gone wrong without a reprex, see here: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/. Its generally best practise when posting here so that people can just stick your code in their R and work out whats causing the issue.

Comment: Does using `scale_color_discrete` instead of `scale_fill_discrete` help?

You might also need to use `values` instead of `labels`